# Route 53 can't change NS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I've migrated one domain to **Route 53**. The migration was successful, but  NS of domain points to NS of previous registrar. I've tried to change the values to new NS generated for `HostedZone`, but the operation is still stuck.  In the dashboard I can see:

> domainname.it   ---  Name server update in progress  ---   2016-12-16
>   18:47:41

After 4 days it's always in "in progress" state.
When I try to change it again, I've got this message:

> "You can't edit NS because you have an pending request"

Amazon do not provide any support for this issue. What can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you **transfer** your domain to Amazon registrar or just created hosted zone in Route53?

Comment: Real domain name would actually help.

Comment: I've transferred domain to Amazon registrar (Gandi). I've done this for two domains. One of them have correct NS generated by amazon, another have NS from previous registrar.

Comment: real name is stresscollection.it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes 6 days to unlock pending request. After that I was able to change NS in 2 minutes.